# Using Auth0.WinformsWPF, how do I obtain and use a refresh token?

Tags: c#, wpf, oauth, vsto, auth0

Thanks for looking.

## Background

I am developing an Outlook add-in that requires our users to obtain a token so that they may interact with our API. We use [Auth0](https://auth0.com) for this.

Essentially, when the user attempts to use a feature from our add-in, they are presented with a sign-in dialog that is powered by Auth0's [Auth0.WinformsWPF](https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.WinformsWPF) nuget package (if they are not yet authenticated):

[image]

Of course, our users do not care to sign in to our API every time the token expires so I need to make use of [Auth0's Refresh Token](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token#use-a-refresh-token) so that if our code attempts to call the API but the token is expired, I can refresh it without asking the user to log back in.

## Problem

I do not see an obvious way to obtain or make use of the refresh token using [Auth0.WinformsWPF](https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.WinformsWPF) package. Launching the above dialog to obtain a token is pretty simple however:

```
auth0.LoginAsync(wrapper, "","openid name email email_verified picture given_name family_name sso").ContinueWith(t => {

//Callback logic after successful authentication.

},
 TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
```

## Question

Preferably using [Auth0.WinformsWPF](https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.WinformsWPF), how do I obtain and use a refresh token? I would very much appreciate some example code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `offline_access` parameter to `scope`. That will instruct Auth0 to return a `refresh_token`

Comment: Thank you Eugenio. I understand the concept but this is still confusing to me: How does Auth0 know which token I am refreshing? How would I make the call from C# using Auth0.WinformsWPF? The code I show in the question is obvious, but that displays a login prompt to the user. We don't want this with the refresh token. Many thanks Eugenio, I look forward to your reply.